# Is there a technical term for swapping words and rearranging affixes to entirely change the meaning of a phrase?

Tags: word-choice

Mi sto riferendo a coppie come le seguenti:

- "ridicolmente fortunato" e "sfortunatamente ridicolo"
- "tremenda disfatta" e "tremendamente fatto" (*fatto* nell'accezione [5.b di Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fatto1_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/), o comunque in quella che si usa comunemente tra giovani)
- "criticare moderatamente" e "moderare criticamente"

C'è un termine per riferirsi a simili coppie? O magari a giochi di parole che fanno leva su tali coppie?

Forse è bene chiarire che sì sto cercando una locuzione con cui indicare le cose sopra, per cui ho scelto [word-choice](/questions/tagged/word-choice), ma la finalità non è quella di inserire la locuzione nel testo, quanto quella di poterne cercare altri esempi su internet.

Comment: Interessante. Mi sembra un meccanismo molto specifico, ma direi che siamo dalle parti delle figure retoriche basate sulla [ripetizione](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ripetizione), come la paronomasia e il poliptoto. Non è nessuna di queste, ma forse possono essere un punto di partenza. (Perché il titolo in inglese e il testo in italiano?)

Comment: Io metterei l'esempio sotto la voce *chiasmo*, che vuol dire 'incrocio', 'scambio', l'etimologia viene dalla forma della lettera X. Vedi questa voce, scolastica ma fatta bene: https://www.studenti.it/chiasmo-significato.html

Answer (score 2):

Antimetabole (an-tee-meh-TA-boe-lee): Figure of emphasis in which the words in one phrase or clause are replicated, exactly or closely, in reverse grammatical order in the next phrase or clause; an inverted order of repeated words in adjacent phrases or clauses (A-B, B-A).

L’antimetabole è una ripetizione invertita, che nella seconda parte ribalta gli elementi della prima e ne cambia il significato.

- non mangia per vivere, vive per mangiare
- pensa quello che dice e dice quello che pensa
- non si prevale con la ragione della forza, ma con la forza della ragione
- l'assenza di prova non è prova dell’assenza